# Docusign account configuration management

Tags: docusignapi

I am writing an application that uses Docusign and I’m trying to figure out the best way to manage my Docusign account in general.

Here is the use case:

1)  My software uses custom Docusign templates and tabs and uses the Docusign API to accomplish populating the templates, tabs, and generating envelopes

2)  The user will have to provide their own Docusign account to use my software

### Questions:

1)  How do I get the custom templates loaded into their Docusign account?

Can templates be shared between totally disparate Docusign accounts?
Other options I think might work are an export or import of the templates (but that is clunky).
Maybe I can use the API to upload the templates as well???

2)  Who’s Docusign Integrator Key do I use?

Do they need to generate one from their Docusign account and I use that one from my software?  Or do I ALWAYS use my developer integrator key???

3)  Who’s API username and password do I use to log in via the API?

I assume theirs,  but I’m not a fan of needing to save a bunch of Docusign passwords in my database.

Any other options for setting this up the right way???

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future inquires, include if you're using REST or SOAP.

Here are the answers to the questions that you have above.

**1) How do I get the custom templates loaded into their Docusign account?
Can templates be shared between totally disparate Docusign accounts?
Other options I think might work are an export or import of the templates (but that is clunky).**

**Maybe I can use the API to upload the templates as well???**

*Templates can only be shared within users on the same account. There isn't a way to upload a template via the API either. You can use composite templates for a standardized template across multiple accounts (depending on SOAP/REST, the coding changes here)*

**2) Who’s Docusign Integrator Key do I use?**

**Do they need to generate one from their Docusign account and I use that one from my software? Or do I ALWAYS use my developer integrator key???**

*Your application will always use your Integrator Key, which will only work in Demo until you go through the Certification to get the Integrator Key promoted to production.*

*More info on that process here: https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/certification*

**3) Who’s API username and password do I use to log in via the API?
I assume theirs, but I’m not a fan of needing to save a bunch of Docusign passwords in my database.**

**Any other options for setting this up the right way???**

*You will need specific permissions enabled on a user and on an account to make API calls successfully. Most integration's use a system user to login and make these calls. If you're working within multiple accounts that you do not have administration over, you will end up running into permission errors.*

It sounds like you're wanting to setup a Partner integration, which does differ a little from a standard integration.

Comment: Thanks Andrew,  makes sense.  You mentioned that a Partner integration differs a little.  How can I get more details on how the Partner integrations work?  I saw online how to apply to be a partner but no info on the integration...

Comment: You would want to follow the guidelines on how to apply to be a partner. That would get you down the path of all of the information for partner integrations.